# Call custom method in tabbar from child view

Tags: ios7, methods, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabbarController that is also a UINavigationController delegate. it has an exposed method that I would like to call from within one of child views (one of the tabs) How do I go about doing this?

Comment: can you just create the method in the child view (view controller) instead? Is it a custom tabbar controller?

Comment: yeah it is custom ... can create the method in the view controller but  that seems like it's a bit of duplication

Comment: if it only needs to be called in one of the tabs/view controllers then it wouldn't be duplicated...maybe i'm not fully understanding the issue